# Explanation of the way to make up your sins quote in Mean Streets

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, mean-streets

[***Mean Streets***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070379/) (1973) includes this quote

> Charlie: You don't make up for your sins in church. You do it in the
>   streets. You do it at home. The rest is bullshit and you know it.

What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I wanted to know the clarification of the quotes. @Paulie_D

Comment: Then perhaps you need to provide some context. Just laying out the quote isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote looks pretty self-explanatory. You don't become a *good person* by praying in church and confessing. **You do it by doing good things to people, by treating your family well.**

The *streets* and *home* are not literal, but metaphorical. They indicate both random strange people (in the street), and loved ones (at home).